# Any similar idioms to the Arabic 'You don't fill my eye'?

Tags: idiom-requests

"You don't fill my eye" is an Arabic idiom.

When looking at somebody, and if that somebody doesn't fill your eye (namely, doesn't occupy all the space in your eye in order for him to be seen clearly and well), that person is not someone you would deign to speak to or look at. He isn't at the same level of intellect or class as you. You see the person as trifling and contemptible.
This saying is patently degrading, however it used playfully.

Examples,

> 1: Why won't you talk to me, or don't I fill your eye?
>
> 2: Perish the thought! You know your value and worth to me, it's just I'm in no mind or mood. Forgive me.

> 1: Why are you looking at me like that?
>
> 2: You don't fill my eye.

In the second example, because the person doesn't fill his eye, occupy all his eye, axiomatically to look at something in more detail we look at length and closely at it. But here he's looking closely out of disgust and no matter how long or how close he looks he won't occupy all his eye space because he sees him as contemptible as it is possible to be.

Any similar idioms?

Comment: A not-so-playful alternative could be **eyesore**, perhaps?

Comment: I like "I couldn't care less about you." English speakers tend to say, "I could care less about you," which is clearly wrong. The former, correct saying means that I could NOT possibly care ANY LESS  for you than I already do. In other words, I'm apathetic (have no feelings at all)  toward you. Don

Comment: *1 Why won't you talk to me, or don't I fill your eye?* -1a Why won't you talk to me,  have you had enough of me? 2. No, no - you're a good person, it's just that I'm busy." ++ 3: *Why are you looking at me like that?*  3a: I've had enough of you.

Comment: His attitude towards them was remote and condescending. *He wouldn’t even give them the time of day.*

Answer (score 4):

***beneath contempt*:**

> If someone or something is beneath contempt, they are so bad or so unimportant that they do not deserve any attention.

Example:

> But he's unworthy of mention; beneath contempt.

([Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/beneath-contempt)) ([Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/beneath-contempt))

***not give someone the time of day*:**

> Not do the slightest favor for; not greet or speak to; have contempt for.

Example:

> I wouldn't give that bastard the time of day.

([The Dictionary of American Slang](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/not-give-someone-the-time-of-day))

Comment: How would you incorporate that in the first example though?

Comment: "Why won't you talk to me, or am I beneath contempt?" "Why won't you talk to me, or can I not have the time of day?"

Answer (score 2):

A somewhat similar pattern in American English goes like this:

1. *What are you looking at?* -- This is generally delivered in a tone of voice that indicates an aggressive challenge.
2. *Not much.*  -- The response is delivered while looking the speaker from number 1 in the eyes, indicating that "not much" refers to the speaker's worth, not some unrelated object.

Determining whether this is done playfully depends on tone of voice and facial expressions.

Comment: This pattern occurs in English English also.

Answer (score 1):

**What am I, chopped liver?**

This phrase can be used to express displeasure at the fact that someone is ignoring you, or otherwise not taking into account your thoughts/feelings. Chopped liver was traditionally served as a side dish (and one that many might find unpalatable), so feeling like "chopped liver" is a feeling of being overlooked and disregarded.

This phrase is typically used by the person being ignored, metaphorically comparing their own perceived stature to a dish that no one wants to touch. It's not normally used as an insult by the person doing the ignoring, however, so you wouldn't typically call someone *else* "chopped liver".

Answer (score 0):

**Condescend** (verb)

> To do something in a way that shows you think it is below your social or professional position - used to show disapproval.
>
> 'Yes. I know,' Clara said, condescending to look at Rose for the first time. ([Longman Dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/condescend))

**Condescending** (adjective)

> Showing or implying condescension by stooping to the level of one's inferiors, esp in a patronizing way. ([Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/condescending))
>
> *'I ​hate the way he's so condescending to his ​staff!'*

Answer (score 0):

Something like **high horse** might work here.

Example:

> Are you on such a high horse, that I am not worth your time?